# Why is my 5-year-old son always interested in baby toys?

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler, age-appropriate, toys

When I take my son to the store and we take a look at the toy section, he always goes straight to the baby toys. And when he picks out a toy that he wants it's always a baby toy.

He has toys for his age group and obviously some that are below and above, too. Example, he has a remote controlled car at home that is intended for 5 years+. He's had it for 2 years now and can use it just fine, but the other day we are in toy isle and he picks out same kind of toy, but for age range 2-4 years.

He also picks out the girly legos over the cool boy legos. Why is that?

He is my only child and I don't plan on having any more. He has friends at school, both boys and girls. Oh and he screams instead of yelling like other boys his age do. And he gets giddy when he's excited. Like flapping his hands like a bird, not an eagle.

Comment: Have you shared your concerns with a doctor, a teacher, a relative or another parent? Does anyone else agree that something is peculiar?  It could simply be that he prefers toys that take no effort and that he yells because that is what works. Do you mean he flaps his hands but close to his body, unlike a bird flying? He might prefer the colours of the 'girl' Legos, I bet it doesn't mean anything. Downvotes might mean the person did not understand your question. Welcome to Parenting.

Comment: why the downvotes? What is unclear about the question?

Comment: @Aquarius TheGirl I am with you on this, but wonder if the flapping hands part was confusing.

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl my guess on the downvotes could be due to comments like _girly legos over the cool boy legos_ as some feel this is not an issue and the parent is making an issue out of nothing. I didn't downvote, just to clarify and think the question is clear enough. I know of a lad who is 7 this time and went through a phase of watching My Little Pony. Loved it but knew himself it was quite girly. Then 6 months later, stopped, went on to watch Lego Ninjas. The flapping is excitement and is quite normal. Wouldn't worry to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

My 6 girl and 4boy year old prefer the baby toys with their 9 month old brother. In the store they too love them. Fun colors sounds and they don't see them every day so it's appealing to be exposed to something new! My 6 year old too does a flapping thing when excited I videotaped it and showed the pediatrician and they said it's common at this age for excitement and during deep concentration with play and I shouldn't worry about how flapping is correlated with autism because it's not well known as a developmental milestone as well.

Comment: I have met a few other moms that agree boys playing with girl toys and dress up makes for a well rounded individual. I grew up not being able to play with my twin brothers remote control car because it was a boy toy and look back at this with a stigma that shouldn't be held. Kids dont know the difference. My husband hates it but in our home I won't make my son conform to society's perception of norms. You love your child that is evident.. enjoy the innocence as long as you can!

Comment: Welcome to the site! May I say I love your name? ;)